# How to split some array to several array for every some index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm trying to split a string by whitespace.

```
var conditionSplit = "item == 2 item !== 1 item <= 5".match(/\S+/g);
```

It will give output like:

```
// ["item", "==", "2", "item", "!==", "1", "item", "<=", "5"];
```

I need the result to be like:

```
// [["item","==","2"],["item","!==","1"],["item","<=","5"]]
```

What should I do to split that array or going from the first result.

Thanks for help.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I typed manually and not carefully

Comment: I would argue that your syntax needs to add a separator.  There's a reason C-like languages have semi-colons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sample output is an error and you really want an array of arrays, where each of the subordinate arrays is three entries long, you can do that by using `forEach` and pushing a new array onto a result array whenever the `index` you're visiting is evenly divisible by 3:

```js
var conditionSplit = "item == 2 item !== 1 item <= 5".match(/\S+/g);
var result = [];
var current;
conditionSplit.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    current = [];
    result.push(current);
  }
  current.push(entry);
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or if you wanted to do it by detecting the `item` string, you just change `if (index % 3 == 0)` to `if (entry == "item")`:

```js
var conditionSplit = "item == 2 item !== 1 item <= 5".match(/\S+/g);
var result = [];
var current;
conditionSplit.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (entry == "item") {
    current = [];
    result.push(current);
  }
  current.push(entry);
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

...but you said you wanted to do it by index, so...

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanations.

Comment: @ivan But this doesn't solve your issue at all. What happens if there're more than 3 items per inner array................ [See my answer which is based on detecting `"item"` string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32923679/411632)

Comment: @Matias I know Mathias, but the first item on the each inner of mine doesn't always start with "item". Besides, the string i have based on some result that always should be 3 items per inner. But thanks for your concern and help, realy apreciated. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @ivan No problem. BTW when you post a question you should be as specific as possible. I mean, if not all expressions will start with `item` you should specify that in your question....

Comment: @ivan BTW, have you checked the "are you looking for parsing JavaScript" part of my answer? In my case, I had to perform actions based on arbitrary expressions and a parser is a better solution than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to match by non-whitespace/whitespace tuples and then add a quantifier:

```
([^\S]+\S*){3}
```

This will leave you with whitespace at the end of the 3rd element though, so trimming may be required

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
// This variable will contain the "array of arrays", where each 
// index will be an array of each expression as you requested...
var allResults = [];

"item == 2 item !== 1 item <= 5"
  .match(/\S+/g)
  .reduce(function(result, next) {
    // Whenever an "item" string is detected, this starts
    // a new array item
    if (next == "item") {
      result = [];
      allResults.push(result);
    }

    result.push(next);
  
    return result;
  }, null);


alert(JSON.stringify(allResults));
```

### Are you looking for parsing JavaScript?

If you're looking for parsing JavaScript, you should take a look [at Esprima](http://esprima.org/) and use an abstract syntax tree to analyze expressions programmatically.

For example, if you split your string by `"item"`, and you parse every expression, you would get something like the following AST:

```
// item == 2 would be:

{
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ExpressionStatement",
            "expression": {
                "type": "BinaryExpression",
                "operator": "==",
                "left": {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "item"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": 2,
                    "raw": "2"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "sourceType": "script"
}
```

It sounds complicated, but parsing makes things easier once you get into it! 
You can play with Esprima [using its online parser demo](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to match item followed by =!<0-9 and split each element.

```
 var sa = "item == 2 item !== 1 item <= 5".match(/item[ =!<0-9]+/g);
        var n = sa.length;
        var ar = new Array(n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ar[i] = sa[i].split(" ");
        document.getElementById('fg').innerHTML = ar;
```